# Automatically add any variables that exist in one data.frame but missing in other data.frames in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, match

Suppose I have a ***reference*** data.frame called `a`. I was wondering how I could automatically add any variables that exist in `a` but missing in other data.frames `b` and `d`?

**NOTE:** My goal is to make a function out of this such that any number of data.frames, and any number of variables can be completed based on a single ***reference*** data.frame.

```
a <- data.frame(x = 2:3, y = 4:5, z = c(T, F)) ## reference data.frame

b <- data.frame(x = 6:7) ## Add y and z here

d <- data.frame(x = 7:8) ## Add y and z here
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing all the data.frames involved share the same number of rows, you can simply:

```
toadd<-setdiff(colnames(a),colnames(b))
b[toadd]<-a[toadd]
```

Wrapping the above in a function:

```
f<-function(refdf, ...) {
    res<-listdf<-list(...)
    res<-lapply(listdf, function(x) {
        toadd<-setdiff(names(refdf),names(x))
        x[toadd]<-refdf[toadd]
        x
    })
    c(list(refdf),res)
}
```

Then try for instance:

```
f(a,b)
f(a,b,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Using a reference data.frame perform a right join in order
# to append required vectors to provided data.frames: 
add_empty_vecs <- function(refdf, ...){
  # Store the names of the other data.frames: df_names => character vector
  df_names <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  # Return the right joined the reference data.frame to the
  # provided data.frames: list => .GlobalEnv()
  setNames(lapply(list(...), function(y){
    merge(refdf, y, by = intersect(names(refdf), names(y)), all.y = TRUE)
    }
  ), c(df_names))
}

# Apply function only df b: 
add_empty_vecs(a, b)

# Apply function to both df b & df d:
add_empty_vecs(a, b, d)

# Apply function to all b, d, e: 
add_empty_vecs(a, b, d, e)
```

Data:

```
a <- data.frame(x = 2:3, y = 4:5, z = c(T, F)) ## reference data.frame

b <- data.frame(x = 6:7) ## Add y and z here

d <- data.frame(x = 7:8) ## Add y and z here

e <- data.frame(x = 9:10)
```